# Fold only comments when file is opened in Vim

Tags: vim, comments, folding

When I am viewing long code files with verbose comments in Vim, I would like to be able to load the files with comments folded but everything else unfolded. The current folding configuration I have in my `.vimrc` is:

```
set foldmethod=syntax
set nofoldenable
```

That way, when I want to start doing folds, I can just start executing `z` commands. But is there a way to only fold the (block) comments?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could execute a global command to close all the block comment folds:

```
:g/^\/\*/foldc
```

This will execute `:help foldclose` on any line that starts with `/*` (a common block comment indicator). Notice the `/` and `*` need to be escaped in this instance. You don't need to escape the `/` if you use a different delimiter (e.g. `:g#^/\*#foldc`). If you want this to happen automatically you could add it in an autocommand. For example:

```
set fdm=syntax fen
augroup closeCommentFolds
   au!
   au FileType javascript %foldo | g/^\/\*/foldc
   au FileType ruby %foldo | g/^=begin/foldc
augroup end
```

Note that in these examples the `^` character in regex specifies that the `/*` and `=begin` matches are at the beginning of the line. If you want to match if there's whitespace between the beginning of the line and the match then use `^\s*` instead of `^`. The `%foldo` will open all folds so that `foldenable` is set, but it won't fold everything (just comments in this case).

Comment: This is a great ansewr. I learned a lot. However, it didn't work out of the box. I had to do `...set fen | %foldopen | %g^/\*@call SilentFold()`, where `SilentFold` is a function I defined to suppress fold errors for lines where the `/*...*/` style is used even though it is not a block comment (yes, I object, but I did not write the code) and uses `normal zc`. Also if you find that what I have done improves the post, feel free to draw from it. (It it is too verbose I would also be curious to know why.) +1 Thank you!

Comment: Actually my answer is behaving strangely as well...it is folding things that aren't comments, i.e. `{...}` blocks.

Comment: @Kazark okay, sorry about the confusion. I believe my updated answer is now working perfectly. Let me know.